# Oracle Apex set session state

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have multiple items on my page, all share the same name structure:

P1_ITEM_NUMBER_1, P1_ITEM_NUMBER_2, P1_ITEM_NUMBER_3 and so on.

I'm trying to set the value for all with a loop, but the set session function is not doing it. Any idea why?

```
declare

v_text varchar2(100);

BEGIN

    FOR v_initial IN 1..100 LOOP
        SELECT text_col,
            id_number
        INTO v_col1,
            v_col2
        FROM my_table;

    v_text := column1;

    APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P1_ITEM_NUMBER_'|| v_initial, v_text);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Text_column is a varchar2 col and id_number is just an ordered sequence (starts with one).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That piece of code is invalid; not that it won't affect session state, it won't even compile because

- you're selecting into variables that aren't declared
- `v_text` is being set to `column1` which is also not declared
- another possible problem is `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` exception raised by `select` statement unless it contains exactly one row; there's no filter there

*Maybe* you meant to do something like this?

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select id_number, text_col from my_table) loop
    apex_util.set_session_state('P1_ITEM_NUMBER_' || cur_r.id_number,
                                 cur_r.text_col);
  end loop;
end;
```